# Retrieving an employee's PTO from Paylocity API

Tags: javascript, api

Does anybody know how to get an employee's PTO from Paylocity? 
They do have the ability to get a specific employee via https://api.paylocity.com/api/v2/companies/{companyId}/employees/{employeeId} but I don't see any PTO data in there.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution here? I'm running into the same issue, and I'm not seeing anything obvious in the documentation - currently looking here: https://docs.paylocity.com/weblink/guides/Paylocity_Web_Services_API/Paylocity_Web_Services_API.htm

Comment: Hi, did You find a solution? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Paylocity Web Services Representative answer.

[image]